# Receber linhas de arquivo, e tratá-las (BASH)

Tags: linux, bash, dialog

Preciso  de um script bash que vai ler um arquivo, reconhecer o delimitador (no caso ";") e armazenar os valores que estão nos delimitadores em variáveis, para posteriormente montar um menu com o dialog...

O que tenho feito até o momento é :

```
#!/bin/bash
file="Tarefas.cfg"
nomeTarefa=''
dirOrigem=''
dirDest=''
tipoBkp=''
agendarBkp=''
compactarBkp=''
gerarLog=''
echo
for linha in $(cat $file)
do
    nomeTarefa=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f1 )
    dirOrigem=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f2 )
    dirDest=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f3 )
    tipoBkp=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f4 )
    agendarBkp=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f5 )
    compactarBkp=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f6 )
    gerarLog=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f7 )
    echo "$nomeTarefa $dirOrigem $dirDest $tipoBkp $agendarBkp $compactarBkp $gerarLog"
    echo
done
```

o arquivo que ele lê, é o seguinte:

```
Minha Tarefa;/home/;/home/;Diferencial;;N;S;
Minha Tarefa;/home/thalesg;/home/;Diferencial;;N;S;
```

O output é o seguinte:

```
Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha

Tarefa /home/ /home/ Diferencial  N S

Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha

Tarefa /home/thalesg /home/ Diferencial  N S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código abaixo resolveu meu problema:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="Tarefas.cfg"
count=0;
declare arrNomeTarefa;
declare arrDirOrigem;
declare arrDirDest;
declare arrTipoBkp;
declare arrAgendarBkp;
declare arrCompactarBkp;
declare arrGerarLog;

function carregaTarefas {
    while IFS=";" read nomeTarefa dirOrigem dirDest tipoBkp agendarBkp compactarBkp gerarLog || [[ -n "$gerarLog" ]]; do #RECEBE NAS VARS OS VALORES DELIMITADOS POR ;
        count=$((count + 1)); #INICIA O COUNT PARA INCREMENTAR O OPTIONS
        options[$count]=$count" $nomeTarefa" #CONCATENA O OPTIONS

        arrNomeTarefa[$count]="$nomeTarefa"
        arrDirOrigem[$count]="$dirOrigem"
        arrDirDest[$count]="$dirDest"
        arrTipoBkp[$count]="$tipoBkp"
        arrAgendarBkp[$count]="$agendarBkp"
        arrCompactarBkp[$count]="$compactarBkp"
        arrGerarLog[$count]="$gerarLog"
    done < $file ##END READ FILE
}

function criaLista {
    options=(${options[@]}) #STRING DINAMICA COM OS NOMES DAS TAREFAS
    cmd=(dialog --keep-tite --menu "Select options:" 22 76 16) #COMANDO DE CRIAÇÃO DA DIALOG
    choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty) #EXECUÇÃO DA DIALOG  

}
```

Comment: @Tiauris, a script está muito interessante (+1) -- lendo a pergunta não era fácil entender o que procuravas. O que é o "22 76 16"?

Comment: @J Joao são parâmetros de Width x Height x "algo que não me lembro no momento" que ajustam o comando **--dialog**

Answer (score 1):

Desculpa: isto é mais um conjunto de comentários que uma resposta...

Como alternativa ao que escreveste, sugeria:

- uso de `while read var`em vez do for (por causa dos espaçoa)
- uso de arrays

(Provavelmente seria melhor escrever este tipo de scripts em perl, python, etc)

```
#!/bin/bash
file="Tarefas.cfg"    
cat $file | while read linha 
do
  arr=(${linha//;/ })                # split por ";"

  echo "==> ${arr[1]} ${arr[2]} "
done
```

Comment: Olá amigo, esqueci de comentar que consegui resolver o problema... Vou postar a resposta